# dealing with lists in Prolog (removing elements)

Tags: list, lambda, prolog

How can I delete all elements from a list which can be divided by 3 (i.e. `x % 3 == 0`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

or much simpler `findall(X,(member(X,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),0 =:= X mod 3),Y).`

Comment: You should have written findall(X,(member(X,[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]),0 =\= X mod 3),Y).

Comment: `findall/3` is not really meant to do that. When I test it overflows on a list with `10000000` elements while normal methods don't.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a predicate removemod(+List,+Mod,?Result):

```
removemod([],_,[]).
removemod([H|T],M,[H|T2]):-
    H mod M =\= 0,
    removemod(T,M,T2).
removemod([H|T],M,T2):-
    H mod M =:= 0,
    removemod(T,M,T2).
```

Seems to work:

```
15 ?- removemod([3,7,5,12,8,2,16,13,9,11,27],3,L).
L = [7, 5, 8, 2, 16, 13, 11] .

16 ?- removemod([66933],3,L).
L = [].
```

Comment: `R is H mod M, R = 0` => `H mod M =:= 0` and `R is H mod M, \+ R = 0` => `H mod M =\= 0`

Comment: and since arithmetic prevents prolog from going multi ways you might as well add a cut in your second clause to remove the retesting in the third clause if you're interesting in saving some speed (at the cost of introducing a red cut :')).

Comment: @Mog: Thanks for the comments, I changed the operators. Not sure about the cut though, I think they should usually be avoided.

Comment: yup, they should be avoided in particular because they often prevent Prolog from being a relational solver and turn it into a functional solver (one solution), and cause several problems about multi way usage of a predicate etc. Here though since you use `=:=` you'll get an instantiation error if you pass free variables as first argument so the multi way usage is limited, and the predicate is deterministic and has only one solution so using a cut isn't __that__ bad.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way of doing this is to use higher order, in SWI for example, there is a nice predicate called  `exclude/3` that does exactly what you want (remove elements based on a predicate):

```
clean(List, FilteredList) :-
    exclude(mod3, List, FilteredList).

mod3(X) :-
    X mod 3 =:= 0.
```

And higher order is way classier with the [lambda library](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/Prolog-inedit/ISO-Hiord):

```
:- use_module(lambda).

filterMod3(List, FilteredList) :-
    exclude(\X^(X mod 3 =:= 0), List, FilteredList).
```